# Need assistance finding reason why audio does not play in Apache Cordova 2.3.0rc1

Tags: cordova, text-to-speech

I am trying to use google's TTS service to pull mp3's into my PhoneGap (Cordova 2.3.0rc1) app and play them.

I need more information as to why the audio stopped working for me. Can someone else confirm that it works or does not work?

This:

```
{
    var url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=are+you+messing+with+me?';
    var snd = new Audio(url);
    snd.load();
    snd.play();
}
```

Results in this:

```
2012-12-24 16:45:54.365 myAPP[1614:907] [LOG] HTML5 audio capable.
2012-12-24 16:45:56.413 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-12-24 16:45:56.437 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2012-12-24 16:45:57.227 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-24 16:45:57.230 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-24 16:45:57.280 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-12-24 16:45:57.414 myAPP[1614:907] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2012-12-24 16:45:57.480 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2012-12-24 16:45:57.522 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay 
2012-12-24 16:45:57.609 myAPP[1614:907] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0 
2012-12-24 16:46:01.150 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0 
2012-12-24 16:46:01.153 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up. 
2012-12-24 16:46:01.163 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1 
2012-12-24 16:46:01.166 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 1 
2012-12-24 16:46:01.191 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.346 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamUnlikelyToKeepUp: 1 -> 0 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.352 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.355 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up. 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.358 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamRanDry: 0 -> 1 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.389 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Took background task assertion (8) for playback stall 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.398 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.403 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up. 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.405 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.408 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause 
2012-12-24 16:46:03.411 myAPP[1614:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
```

The other alternative is to do a jquery download and play it out of a div....?

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Well the Audio tag api is not well supported in the web view which is probably where you are running into problems. You may want to switch to using the [PhoneGap Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) to play your mp3 file. At some point I've been meaning to re-write this API to conform to the Audio API but I haven't had time for it yet.

Also, if you just want to TTS stuff why don't you use the [TTS Plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/TTS) I wrote to do the conversion on the device?